# addTraget to UIButton in UIView. getting error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, swift4

I have a UIView class and inside it I have a UIButton and when clicked it supposed to open a UIViewController class. However every time I click it I get an error in AppDelegate - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. terminal: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

```
lazy var signupButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Sign me up", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogin(vc:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func handleLogin(vc: UIViewController) {
    let loginController = LoginController()
    vc.present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let width = self.view.frame.size.width
        let height = self.view.frame.size.height
        
        let angleView = AngleView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - width/2,
                                                y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - height/2,
                                                width: width,
                                                height: height))
        
        self.view.addSubview(angleView)
    }

Comment: And what's the full error message? Are you sur `let loginController = LoginController()` is the good way to create your instance of `LoginViewController`? Does it have a Storyboard/Xib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the parameter to `func handleLogin`. You have it set up to expect an instance of a `UIViewController` but it will actually be the sender of the selector, which will be a `UIButton` in this case.

You need to update it to the following:

```
@objc func handleLogin(sender: UIButton) {
   let loginController = LoginController()
   present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You could alternately do this since you don't need the sender parameter at all.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button

@objc func handleLogin() {
   let loginController = LoginController()
   present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```